# Finding similarity between two histogram plots

Tags: python, scikit-learn, similarity, distance, plotting

I have data census(name, sex, age, capital_gain) and I want to plot all possible views (in a histogram) and find the most interesting view based on the distinction to other views.

So, I have to compute the similarity between two histogram plots, for example:

1. Average Capital Gain vs Sex (which computed by aggregate Capital gain to Sex)

[image: Capital gain vs Sex]

2. Average age vs Sex (which computed by aggregate average age to sex)

[image: Age vs Sex]

My questions is, what kind of measurement that can be used to check the similarity between those two histogram plots? I consider the features that want to be compared are (x-axis, y-axis, and pattern of the histogram)

I really not sure about distance function that can be used for this case. I know Jaccard distance, but not sure it can be used in this situation or not.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious what other people will say, but one option is to use [KL-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition).  If your two histograms have the same x-axis, you can divide every column by the total count to convert counts to proportions. Then you could treat the histograms as probability mass, and use the KL-divergence.  KL-divergence is really a measure of the distance between two probability distributions, but histograms are an approximation of a discrete distribution. You'd pick one of your distributions to be P and one to be Q, then calculate $-\sum_x P(X)\log{\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}}$ where $x$ is each bin on the x-axis of the histogram.  Be aware that this distance metric is *directional*, meaning you'll get a different answer if you swap P and Q.  The reason is that the KL-divergence is a measure of information transfer (like, the information you gain by moving from Q to P), but I think that's irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Those plots you're showing are not histograms, they're just bar charts. In a histogram, the height of the bars is a count of how many data points fall in the bucket represented by that value on the X axis (e.g. how many people of that particular age or age group).

What you could do is plot a histogram of the *men's* ages (how many men of each age or age group) and compare it with a histogram of the *women's* ages. It's not clear what it would mean to compare a histogram of the men's ages with, say, a histogram of their wealth.

Computing the similarity between two histograms (or distributions) of the same variable can be done by adapting Jaccard similarity (see [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9ce4/16e3eb2fcffa40b226fece01437c61afba84.pdf) for an example).

You might find a high level of similarity (say 0.9) for age distribution but a low similarity for wealth. The interesting ones are perhaps those where the histograms are dissimilar (things are very different for men and women).